# Is there a bijection between real numbers and continued fractions?

Tags: continued-fractions

It is known that there is a bijection between rational numbers and finite continued fractions, so every rational number is uniquelly identified by a finite continued fractions and vice versa. It is also known that for any irrational number, we can find an infinite continued fractions, but I don't have information is it a unique. If so, than we can conclude that there is a bijection between real numbers and continued fractions.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's unique for irrationals. But you don't really need that. There can't be more continued fractions than $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb R|$

Comment: For rationals, it isn't a bijection: each rational has two expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the numerator of each such [nested fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is $1$. But if you're inquiring about [generalized continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), then the answer is obviously [no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#.CF.80).